# Why this php code returns "true"?

Tags: php

I have the next php code which verifies if the user exists and the password is good. The problem is that when the user does not exists, if you don't pass any password the code returns "true".

```
$apodo= $_GET['apodo']; //Login por mail
$userPass= $_GET['clave'];
//Iniciamos la solicitud de información
$server = "localhost";
$conn = mysqli_connect($server, "root", "", "_v2");
if (!$conn) {
    echo "Error: No se pudo conectar a MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "errno de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "error de depuración: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM kiroldb_v2.Usuario WHERE apodo='$apodo'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$usuario = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if(strcmp($userPass,$usuario['clave'])==0){
    echo "true";
    }else{
            echo "false";
    }
?>
```

Where is the problem?

Edit 1: Solved adding another clause inside the first comparation.

Comment: side note: this code is vulnerable to **SQL Injection** - just imagine a value for apodo like `'; DROP TABLE kiroldb_v2.Usuario; --`. use **parameterized statements** also: *everytime you store an unhashed password, root moves a kitten to /dev/null* - storing plaintext passwords is among the worst things you can do to your users, ever! use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`

Comment: add an additional clause

Comment: btw, don't use this in a live environment, you will get hacked. Unless you're a sucker for punishment and like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advise @FranzGleichmann. This code is for a basic basic basic application that i use for another porpose. Anyway, you are right and yours, is a good lesson for me.

Comment: I solved it adding another clause. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
if(strcmp($userPass,$usuario['clave'])==0){
```

In case the user doesn't exist and no password has been entered:

> $userPass equals ""
>
> $usuario['clave'] equals null or "" as well.

So the comparison conditions return true.

In order to overcome it you need to add another condition to make sure the user exists.

```
if(strcmp($userPass,$usuario['clave'])==0 && $usario['id'] > 0){
```

**A better idea** would be to add a comparison of the password in the SQL query and check if such a user exist.

Comment: Please consider approving my answer if it helped you. thanks.